# what is the maximom order of an element is $\mathbb S_{15}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $S_n$ be the permutation group of order $n$. What is the maximom order of an element on $\mathbb S_{15}$.

Is there any way to find maximom order of an element in $\mathbb S_{15}$ or find the order of an arbitary element in $\mathbb A_n$ and $\mathbb S_n$

Comment: Hint: What are the possible cycle structures of elements in $\mathbb{S}_{15}$? Using that for disjoint cycles $\sigma_i$ we have $\left|\prod_i \sigma_i\right| = \text{lcm}(|\sigma_1|, \ldots |\sigma_k|)$ gives the order of all elements of a certain cycle type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of an element $g$ in $S_n$ is the LCM of the length of cycles in
the factorizetion of $g$ into disjoint cycles. From here it is a question in number theory. I thing for $n=15$ the answer $105=7\cdot 5\cdot 3$.

Comment: $105$ is indeed correct (as confirmed by a quick computation in magma).

Comment: What is $g$ in your text

Comment: Interested in the same question, can you please explain how did you get $105=7\cdot5\cdot3$ ?

Comment: @grayQuant I am not sure I understand your question. $105$ is divisble by $3$, divide and get $105=3\cdot 35$. Since $35=5\cdot 7$ we get $105=3\cdot 5\cdot 7$.

Comment: How did you get 105?

Comment: @grayQuant we looking for elements in $S_{15}$. then we looking on length of cycles $n_1,n_2,\ldots ,n_r$ such that $n_1+n_2+\ldots +n_r\leq 15$ and LCM$(n_1,n_2,\ldots ,n_r)$ is maximal. I found that $3,5,7$ is the best possibility.

Comment: So for $S_14$, is it $2(5)(7)=70$?

Comment: @grayQuant I think in $S_{14}$ it is $3\cdot 4\cdot 7=84$. There is no general solution to this problem.